# Restore firefox saving downloads to /tmp

Tags: firefox, download, upgrade

As the result of upgrading to the 22.04 LTS, the behavior of ff's downloading has changed.  I've read a few posts about this, but haven't seen anything relevant to solving my problem.  Specifically, I want ff to download all files to `/tmp/`.  In the `Settings` tab using the `Browse` method, I select `/tmp/`, but it the setting then shows  `/run/user/1000/doc/fa9c1cc2/tmp⁩`.  If I try using this set up, the downloads fail.  If I use `~/Downloads`, it works, but that's not what I want.

Can someone tell me how to ff to download files to `/tmp/`?  Below is a screen shot of my `about:config` settings:
[image: screenshot of advanced settings]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to switch to using a .deb rather than a snap.  I did this by creating the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mozillateam-ubuntu-ppa-jammy.list` with the code `deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu/ jammy main` and then downloading the priority of snaps over .debs following the instructions here: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/04/how-to-install-firefox-deb-apt-ubuntu-22-04

Answer (score 5):

I successfully achieved this by setting the following property in about:config :

```
browser.download.start_downloads_in_tmp_dir = true
```

Comment: How did configure the download dir? When I do that and configure `browser.download.dir` manually (in `about:config`) to `/tmp`, the files seem to end up in nirvana: I can find them neither in `/tmp` nor in my home; I've no idea where they get saved to now.

Comment: I didn't. `browser.download.dir` is default (click trash icon). What I wanted to go to `/tmp` is the multiple PDF files I read each day, but don't want to keep. Firefox saves them in `/tmp` and opens them with Okular. For others downloads, I configured Firefox to ask me what to do. It selects the last used directory, then ask me to confirm.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be no "good" way to do this; this is a moderately fundamental limitation of snaps, and firefox has been repackaged as a snap in Jammy. However, two hack solutions from https://askubuntu.com/questions/1263843/how-to-allow-snap-applications-to-access-tmp-folder are:

1. Bind-mount your tmp folder into your home directory:

```
mkdir /home/you/.tmp
sudo mount --bind /tmp /home/you/.tmp/
```

(can be made permanent via fstab)

2. Auto-clear your downloads folder on startup: `sudo crontab -e` followed by adding `@reboot rm -rf /home/you/downloads/*` to the crontab.

Both of these solutions entail having an extra directory in your home folder :( It seems this is the design trend being followed by Ubuntu with the move to snaps and Wayland, trying to confine things and bring more security guarantees at the cost of flexibility. Such is life!

Comment: Thanks for the info.  While when I first upgraded I was using a snap for firefox, but I actually removed that and installed via .deb.  I will try your bind approach, nonetheless.

Comment: The firefox deb seems to just be a stub which pulls down the snap :(

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on that.  I've removed the snap again and given it low priority using these [OMGU instructions](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/04/how-to-install-firefox-deb-apt-ubuntu-22-04)

Comment: From what I can tell, flatpak Firefox also has this problem, so unfortunately the issue is not restricted to snaps. :-/

Answer (score 1):

For me, the simple way to solve this problem encountered on my new kubuntu 22.04 fresh install (packed with Firefox 110.0) was to enter **about:config** and change the original setting browser.download.lastDir to /home/x___y___z/Downloads, and then set to "true" the option browser.download.useDownloadDir, as show in the next image:
[browser-download-setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkbqU.png)

Comment: i am so sorry to report that the initial solution exposed in my comment is gone.  machine reboot, Firefox reload, and again.. and again... same problem: all downloads directly goes to /run/user/1000/doc/....  
pfff...
and another problem detected: if you try to save the files to another location, and next, try to delete that "image" that appears (decide you or not) inside /run/user/1000/doc/...  both files were gone...
Amazing!
Please remove, not only firefox.
Remove ALL SNAP things!
https://www.debugpoint.com/remove-snap-ubuntu/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Audrey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73429305/1169233), I found an acceptable workaround by setting the downloads folder to `/var/tmp` instead.